# ¿Qué quiere decir «comer cuento»?

Tags: modismos, hispanoamérica, colombia

La frase es: «Ella no le come cuento a nada.»

¿A qué se refiere «le»? ¿A ella o a nada?

¿Supongo que quiere decir que ella no cree nada?

¿Esto es un colombianismo o se usa en todas partes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hasta donde sé es una «[colombianada](https://dgaleano.blogspot.com/2009/02/version-7-colombianadas.html)» <sub>(probablemente estaré equivocado)</sub> y es muy común para nosotros.

De manera general «le» se refiere a «quién está echando el cuento».

Ejemplo:

> Ella no le come cuento al amigo

Quiere decir que un amigo le está *echando un cuento* y ella no se lo cree

En el caso de «a nada» simplemente quiere decir que ella es una persona que no «come cuentos» de ninguna clase.

Existen personas que creen cualquier cosa que les cuentan y lo opuesto es el que «no le come cuento a nada/nadie»

Sería como si en inglés existiera un antónimo de **gullible**.  Lo más aproximado, aunque a mi no me suena como sinónimo exacto, sería la palabra «incrédulo/a».